# if $\vert f(z)\vert\leq\frac{1}{\vert \sin{z} \vert}$ then $f\equiv0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be an entire function with
$$\vert f(z)\vert\leq\frac{1}{\vert \sin{z} \vert}$$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}\backslash\pi\mathbb{Z}$. I have to show that $f\equiv0$.

Obviously $f$ can not be a non constant polynomial because in this case $\lim_{\vert z\vert\to\infty}\vert f(z)\vert=\infty$ what would contradict the assumption since $\frac{1}{\sin{z}}$ is periodic and gets "infinitely small infinitely many times" since $\sin{z}$ is surjective. If $f$ was constant than it have to be $f\equiv0$ because of the same reasoning.

But I am unable to prove that $f$ can not be entire transcendental. I more like proved that it is but I can not find the error in my argumentation. From Casorati Weierstrass it follows that $f$ is entire transcendental if and only if there exists Sequences $(z_n), (w_n)\subset\mathbb{C}$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=\infty$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}w_n=\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(z_n)=c$ with $c\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(w_n)=\infty$.

I am the opinion that this characterization of entire transcendental functions is true in the case $\vert f(z)\vert = \frac{1}{\vert \sin z\vert}$ (what would be a counterexample since this equality implies $\vert f(z)\vert\leq\frac{1}{\vert \sin{z} \vert}$). Because I could define $z_n=2\pi n -\frac{1}{n}$ and $w_n=1+2\pi n$. Obviously both sequences head to infinity, but $(f(w_n))_n$ is constant and therefore converces, and $(f(z_n))_n$ goes to infinity. So in this case $f$ would be entire transcendental. However there must be a mistake in my argumentation but I can not spot it.

I would be very thankful for any hints how to solve this exercise and where I made an error in my obviously wrong proof.

Comment: Let $g(z)= f(z) \cdot \sin (z)$. Then $|g(z)| \le 1$ for all $z$. Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $f(z)\sin z$ is a bounded entire function and it is a constant by Liouville's Theorem.

Comment: Oke I feel so stupid right now..
Since $\sin(0)=0$ it implies $g(0)=0$. But since $g$ is constant and $\sin(z)$ is surjective, it must be $f\equiv0$.

Comment: Yes. But you do not need surjectivity. $g(0) = 0$ and $g$ being constant suffices as an argument